# var=$[3 * 2] seem conflict with intuitive perception

Tags: bash

I am confused about the outer `$` in `var3=$[$var1 * $var2]`

Suppose the following script:

```
$ var1=5; var2=6; var3=$[$var1 * $var2]; echo $var3
30
```

If `$` is removed, it report error:

```
$ var1=5; var2=6; var3=[$var1 * $var2]; echo $var3
-bash: Algorithms: command not found
30
$ var=[3 * 2]; echo $var
-bash: Algorithms: command not found
[3*2]
```

I feel it very strange it to declare;

```
$ var=$[3 * 2]; echo $var
6
```

Perform very likely from intuitive perception:

```
$ var=$6; echo $var
```

It's odd.

What's the mechanism which force the syntax should do it this way?

is it variable substitution?

Comment: [`$[ EXPRESSION ]` is depreciated, Use `$((EXPRESSION))` syntax instead](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). And `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`.

Comment: could you please transmit the comment to answer. @devWeek

Comment: Do you have a file called `Algorithms` in the directory where you ran that command? The `*` was expanded as a file glob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `$[ ... ]` (and the standard form, `$(( ... ))`) interpret their contents as arithmetic expressions. Without the `$`, it doesn't. It might interpret it as something completely different. You can see this better by `echo`ing the result directly:

```
$ var1=5; var2=6
$ echo $[$var1 * $var2]    # This gets interpreted as arithmetic
30
$ echo [$var1 * $var2]    # This doesn't
[5 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt 6]
```

Here, `[$var1` and `$var2]` are treated as completely separate strings, which evaluate to "[5" and "6]" respectively. The `*`, on the other hand, got interpreted as a filename wildcard and expanded to a list of files in the current directory. Now, in the case of your command:

```
$ var3=[$var1 * $var2]
-bash: file1.txt: command not found
```

What's happening is very similar to the above: the `*` expands to a list of files, so the command is effectively:

```
var3=[5 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt 6]
```

...which is interpreted as `var=value command arguments...`, that is it tries to set the variable `var3` to "[5" for the command `file1.txt` with the arguments "file2.txt", "file3.txt", etc. Except that in your case, the first file (or directory) in the current directory is named "Algorithms" instead of "file1.txt". In either case, it's not a valid command name, so you get a "command not found" error.

BTW, as @devWeek pointed out, `$[ ]` is deprecated, and you should use `$(( ))` instead. But again, the `$` is not optional:

```
$ echo $(($var1 * $var2))    # This gets interpreted as arithmetic
30
$ echo (($var1 * $var2))    # This doesn't
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

BTW2, `$6` means something still different; it refers to the sixth argument to the current script/function/whatever. In an interactive shell, there generally aren't any arguments, so it will evaluate to nothing:

```
$ echo $[ 6 ] placeholder    # This gets interpreted as arithmetic
6 placeholder
$ echo $6 placeholder    # This doesn't
placeholder
```

Basic takeaway: shell syntax is *extremely picky*, and not particularly intuitive. Leave out a symbol or two (or even just add or remove a space in the wrong place), and you change the meaning completely.

Comment: `$(( ))` is not a newer form, it exists since 1988.

Comment: @schily Hmm, I didn't realize that `$[ ]` dates from about the same time (see [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-04/msg00034.html)), so I changed my description of `$(( ))` to "standard" (which it is; see section 2.6.4 of the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)).

Comment: So `$(( ))` is at least 2 years older as it has been in ksh88 already.

Answer (score -4):

The command alias [=test has been used on linux so that the [ character also calls the test command.

For proof of that try `man [`

Im actually trying to post a question or bug report about $(xstr) parsing in BASH. I think the evaluation occurs like $(0) and the data stream is injected to the $0 variable which is always bash.

Its important to note that the $ character is used for strings is some languages but in bash it is used for command line arguments (aka parameters) also in regex used in sed command the $ is equivalant to pressing the END key.

I found that you need to read `man bash` to learn the order of expansion.

Im trying to explain the when the BASH looks at the $ character is running BASH again seems like a huge change for memory leaks.

Let me show you

//ignore from top command then i button    [1]+  Stopped                 top

```
root@ubuntu-studio:/var# echo $0
bash
root@ubuntu-studio:/var# echo $(0)
0: command not found
```

Comment: No, `$[...]` is a deprecated form of `$((...))` in `bash`.

Comment: what is $0 then or $(0)

Comment: `$0` is the zeroth command line argument (usually the name of the program) and `$(0)` is a command substitution that tries to run a command called `0`.

Comment: `$[` is definitely not the same as `[`